# having problem with my codes, how too calcualte the two extra dollars for 3D movies

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code I wrote and I am not able to get the surcharge to add into the final price of the ticket:

```
#program will compute the price of a theater ticket
#cost of a ticket will be 10 dollars $
#3D _ticket will cost a surcharge of 2 $
#senior discount will be 20%
#children discount will be 10%
#value will be in $

ticket = 10
senior discount = .8
children discount = .9
surcharge = +2

#ask user to input age, and if the move is in 3D
num = int(input('enter buyers age: \n'))
question1 = input('is the movie in 3D? \n')


#if statements determine discount for seniors and children and compute the price
if num > 60:
    print('the senior ticket cost is: $', ticket * .8)
    
if num < 12:
    print('the children cost of the ticket is $', ticket * .9)

elif num >= 12 and num <=60:
    print('cost of the adult ticket is $', ticket)

if question1 == 'yes':
    print('print price of ticket with surcharge is $',   ticket +2)

elif question1 == 'no':
    print('no surcharge!')

else:
    print('invalid')  #answer should be yes or no

print('num + question1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only printing the calculated value of the ticket, but you are not updating the actual variable to be used in later steps. For example, instead of

```
if num < 12:
    print('the children cost of the ticket is $', ticket * .9)
```

you should write

```
if num < 12:
    ticket = ticket * 0.9
    print('the children cost of the ticket is $', ticket)
```

Update all calculations similar to the above example I did for you.

Comment: thank you very much ran great, how did  it change the way that worked?

Comment: As I said, you were not updating the actual ticket price but only printing the new value. The value of the `ticket` variable stayed `10` throughout your code since you never reassigned it. You must specifically tell Python to update a variable using `ticket = <...new value...>`

Comment: @dbaby if this answer is helpful, can you mark it as accepted by clicking on the check box besides the answer? That'll give closure to your question and others with a similar question will be encouraged to find this answer.